# Amazon Autoscale & Github

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I have installed centos 6.5 / apache and gitbhub on my remote server. Is it possible when the server starts (or every hour) that it pull the latest commit from my production branch, force overwriting everything it had locally?

I see the use of the git push command but since the auto-scale will happen behind the firewall, it's basically useless.

If this was already answered here, I am sorry.

Comment: How does auto-scale relate to this?

Comment: Autoscale create a new instance from a snapshot that do not have the latest version of the site obviously. Therefore when the server come online, it must download from git the latest commit for the prod branch. -- On the other hand, I cannot do a git push to the news instance since I don't know it's url behind the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add to the [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for your instance the following command. It needs to be run on the a directory where your git repository for your code is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull -f origin <your branch>
```

or if you don't want to care about which directory you are in:

```
git --git-dir=<your-git-repo-directory>/.git --work-tree=<your-git-repo-directory> reset --hard HEAD
git --git-dir=<your-git-repo-directory>/.git --work-tree=<your-git-repo-directory> pull -f origin <your branch>
```

To make it run every hour you can add it as cron job by creating a file under `/etc/cron.d/` with the following content:

```
0 * * * * <your-user> git --git-dir=<your-git-repo-directory>/.git --work-tree=<your-git-repo-directory> reset --hard HEAD
1 * * * * <your-user> git --git-dir=<your-git-repo-directory>/.git --work-tree=<your-git-repo-directory> pull -f origin <your branch>
```